# Creating users from a CSV file with extra col

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, gmaps4rails

Part of the current project i'm working on uploads csv files to my web server that I want to use to create Users/points for gmaps4rails. My CSV file however has more than just the lng lat and title fields that I need as params for the new user. 
Can I still use the row.to_hash function ? I also tried User.latitude = row.to_hash['lat'] etc to only grab the col I need

Additionally i'm confused where to put this. I tried the controller and model and either way apache just gave me the "we are sorry" page and asked me to look at the log which didn't give me any information I could use to trace the problem. which makes it very hard to self problem solve.

```
require 'csv'    

CSV.foreach('lib/data/cur.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  User.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

example of my CSV - The col A-E aren't needed to plot the point - should I just add them as col to the schema anyway so I can use the row.to_hash ?

```
ID,lat,A,lng,B,C,D,E

$26A8,3023.1214,N,9744.5808,W,0.78,179.75,08102,U
$26A9,3023.0842,N,9744.6805,W,0.78,179.75,08102,U
$26AA,3022.9717,N,9744.5025,W,0.78,179.75,08102,U
```

EDIT: this is the current iteration of my method in the User model

```
    CSV.foreach('lib/data/cur.csv', headers: true) do |row|
      user = find_by_id(row['ID']) || new
      attributes = {latitude: row['lat'].to_f, longitude: row['lng'].to_f, title: row['ID'].to_hash}
      begin
        User.create!(attributes)
      rescue => e
        "User failed to create with #{attributes} attributes because of #{e.message}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the values don't store them in the db.  To avoid storing all of the values you can do the following:

```
CSV.foreach('lib/data/cur.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  User.create!(lat: row['lat'].to_f, lng: row['lng'].to_f)
end
```

As far as where to put this, I would put it in either the seeds.rb file or in a rake task.  If the Users are required for the application to run as expected put them in seeds.  If you are just creating data then I would do it in a rake task.  You may want to add in some error handling as well because whoever/whatever is creating your CSV will not be perfect.

so

```
CSV.foreach('lib/data/cur.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  attributes = {lat: row['lat'].to_f, lng: row['lng'].to_f}
  begin
    User.create!(attributes)
  rescue => e
    "User failed to create with #{attributes} attributes because of #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

Comment: it is my understanding that seeds if for the inital setup - i need to be able to call this method repeatedly bc i will be overwriting cur.csv as the data changes

Comment: rake tasks are called from the terminal, at least as far as I know, which is why I was trying to put it in a method

Comment: do i need to do row['lat'].to_f to turn it into a float ?

Comment: Yes you will want to call .to_f on it if that is the column type.  You can certainly do the same thing in a controller action but you will need to include "require 'csv'" where ever you are  using the CSV.foreach method.  You could also add a method on the user model that does this and call that from a controller action.  That way you don't have to require csv in your controller(Which is bad form)

Comment: I have basically what you suggest in a self.load method in my User model - I try calling it in the controller by making a method load that calls User.load but it breaks the website and the apahce error log doesn't tell me why

Comment: I was having a hard time putting the code in the comment so i made an edit to the question and added it  - see above also thank you @ruby_newbie for helping

Comment: I can't tell if I have made progress or not, I made a button that calls the controller method - should redirect back to the main page so that it will list the new users but instead it stays on a blank page - i can't tell if the code is executing or not - again the apache error log tells me nothing but at least it isn't giving me the sorry page -- any suggestions on debugging procedures ?

Comment: I don't think you can call .to_hash on the id row.  That is probably what is breaking it.  Try using .to_s instead

Comment: Also If you are not already using pry you should install it in your local environment.  It can be really helpful in these type of situations.  That and tests, you should write tests rather than digging through the logs.

Comment: thank you - i'm still working on the problem- it says "No route matches [POST]" so i think i'm dealing with a different problem than .to_hash - i've been preoccupied with school starting back up -- i need to do some more research